# search for a value in an object at runtime [QuickWatch enhancement]

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, add-in

sometimes I waste my time searching for a value in an object at runtime.
Certainly you-all know this task --> open the QuickWatch view and browse through the properties until you find what you're looking for.

I'm looking for a tool/add-in/extension where it is possible to search for a value in object.
The QuickWatch view with a search enhancement would be perferct :)

sb. knows a tool?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I wrote a commercial extension to Visual Studio (called ["OzCode"](http://www.oz-code.com)) that does exactly what you're asking for - it's a "QuickWatch view with a search enhancement", as it replaces Visual Studio's QuickWatch with its own QuickWatch window that has a [search box](http://o.oz-code.com/features/#search):

[image: BugAid QuickWatch Window]

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to define the amount of levels to search through?

Comment: In the current version the amount of levels is hardecoded to 3, but in the next version (to be released soon) it will be configurable through the Options dialog.

Comment: It seems like BugAid website is down and been replaced by [OzCode](http://www.oz-code.com/) if I'm right.

Answer (score 4):

**Immediate / Command window**

A possible way to achieve that would be to write `? YourObject` in Visual Studio's [Immediate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or [Command window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c785s0kz.aspx). This command will print all values of your object and you can then simply search it with <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

**Custom macro**

Another possibility is to run a custom macro when a TracePoint was hit in Visual Studio like explained by Scott Guthrie in this excellent blog post:

- [Debugging Tips with Visual Studio 2010 (TracePoints – Running a Custom Macro)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/18/debugging-tips-with-visual-studio-2010.aspx)

The macro explained in this blog post automatically outputs all of the local variables when a TracePoint was hit, but the general idea would go in the same direction.

Comment: Good idea, thanks. I didn't think anything of it. But I'll detect my value only on the first level of my object. Further i want to search through my object recursively.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm not aware of any add-in or so to do what you want, but I added another possible solution to my answer using a custom macro.

Comment: incase if you have no idea on how to open command window shortcut is Cntrl+Alt+A   source: http://www.dofactory.com/reference/visual-studio-shortcuts

Comment: sometimes command window will not show complete expanded results for internal objects.