# Search in debug mode inside an object

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Is it possible to search inside an object for values and/or other field while debugging a C# application?
I'm looking for a deep search that can drill down the object for many levels.

What I'm looking for is a way to search (like F3 for documents search) inside very complex objects (while debugging, in the Quick watch window for example).

Comment: Try using F10 or F11 to get further down your objects. Also, there is built-in functionality to view object values etc.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific what you mean by "search" to get better answers. I just assumed it meant to be able to access values. So what do you want to search by? Property type? How can you search for values if the property isn't string, number or bool? Give an example of what you want to be able to do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use [OzCode](http://www.oz-code.com) (an add-on for Visual Studio), which lets you [search](http://o.oz-code.com/features#search) for the members you want to see from within the on-hover-DataTip or the QuickWatch window.

See example in the following screenshot:

[image: Search Feature]

**Full disclosure**: I am the co-creator of "OzCode".

Comment: Sadly, the website is gone (replaced with search engine spam) and I'm not able to find this extension anywhere on the extension gallery.

Comment: @Kcoder Sorry, the product was renamed [OzCode](http://www.oz-code.com) many years ago.

Comment: Sadly you need a paid license even if you're not a corporate user ...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do whitout an add-on it can be done by going to the object list,  selecting all objects (ctrl+a) and copy them to a searchable text-editor. This will give you a newline seperated list.

[image]

Comment: Very useful when searching code written by someone else when you don't where they have put stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no built-in feature to lets you, dive in deep in the objects in debugging mode, Unless use extensions if available.

Comment: thanks for voting, but as you can see @Shahar wrote 'search' it means the feature to type something in it and search for it. Of course you can navigate in object in debug, I meant there is no built-in feature to search in objects.

Answer (score 1):

Besides Wilson Kao's post, you can also try the simplest approach that I use:

1. Put a breakpoint at a place where a variable referencing the object will be used.
2. Hover mouse over the variable when the breakpoint is hit. You should see a popup showing the top level properties of the object.
3. Use the little + buttons on the left to go deeper into the object. It could get confusing.

You can also pin certain properties that you find deep down so you don't have to look for them again and again (pin button appears on the right side of each property when you hover over the property)

Here's an exmaple of what it looks like (the variable is books):
[image: Example]

Source: http://blogesh.wordpress.com/2008/09/09/visual-studio-debugging-tips-and-tricks/

Edit: There is a way to get all the properties and their values that you access through the manual hover-and-click method (ie in the above image, you can get ISBN and its value through code). However you have to use Visual Basic code. You can then do a search on the results for a specific value.

First, you need to go read up on Tracepoints and custom Macros:
[Click and go to "TracePoints – Running a Custom Macro"](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/18/debugging-tips-with-visual-studio-2010.aspx)
[Also, here](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/vb/print.php/c16235)

Next you need to make a Macro to do what you want.
In Visual Studio, go to **Tools -> Macros -> Macros IDE...**
Add a new Macro. There should be a preset blank one called Module 1. In here, you add routines to do what you want. The following is a Macro I made that will go through a certain variable and output the properties of it (basically, output the data you get in the cover-and-click method). This outputs to the Output window, which you can open through **View -> Output**.

```
    Sub DisplayAllProperties()
    Dim outputWindow As EnvDTE.OutputWindow
    outputWindow = DTE.Windows.Item(EnvDTE.Constants.vsWindowKindOutput).Object

    Dim currentStackFrame As EnvDTE.StackFrame
    currentStackFrame = DTE.Debugger.CurrentStackFrame

    outputWindow.ActivePane.OutputString("*Dumping Local Variables*" + vbCrLf)

    For Each exp As EnvDTE.Expression In currentStackFrame.Locals
        If (exp.Name = "this") Then ' Here, I am only searching in a variable named "this"
            outputWindow.ActivePane.OutputString("- " + exp.Name + ": " + exp.Value.ToString() + vbCrLf)

            helperDisplay(exp.DataMembers, outputWindow, 1)
        End If

    Next
End Sub

Private Sub helperDisplay(ByRef exps As EnvDTE.Expressions, ByRef OutputWindow As EnvDTE.OutputWindow, ByVal n As Integer)

    For Each ex In exps
        helperTabs(n, OutputWindow)

        If (ex.Name = "Non-Public members" Or ex.Name = "Static members") Then
            OutputWindow.ActivePane.OutputString("~ " + ex.Name + ": There are " + ex.DataMembers.Count.ToString + vbCrLf)
        Else
            OutputWindow.ActivePane.OutputString("~ " + ex.Name + ": " + ex.Value.ToString() + vbCrLf)
            If (ex.DataMembers.Count <> 0) Then
                helperDisplay(ex.DataMembers, OutputWindow, n + 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub helperTabs(ByVal n As Integer, ByRef OutputWindow As EnvDTE.OutputWindow)
    For i = 1 To n Step 1
        OutputWindow.ActivePane.OutputString(vbTab)
    Next
End Sub
```

This code is giving me exceptions for some DevExpress controls I tested it on. I think it's because some values can't be accessed. I have never coded in VB before so there are probably bugs in there...Play with it and see if it can do what you want (ie output only the properties that match what you need). The good part is, you can change the Macro code AS you are debugging, so no need to stop your project while you edit the Macro!

To use the Macro, you need to put a breakpoint somewhere in your code that will be hit, and will be able to access the object you want.
-> Right click the breakpoint and go to **When Hit...** Check off **Run a macro:** and select your Macro from the dropdown.

Comment: The manual walk inside an object I know, the pin I didn't notice which is cool! :)    But what I'm looking for is a way to search (like F3 for documents search) inside very complex objects.   In the given example it would be search for fields called 'Title' or for values that contain 'Web Parts'.  I can't find it in the object's definition because I don't have the source code.

Comment: Oh ok. I had an idea of using custom macros in TracePoints that Visual Studio's debugger provides. So I googled it and found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275078/search-for-a-value-in-an-object-at-runtime-quickwatch-enhancement It's funny because the link it provides is the same one I learned about TracePoints from! The macro language is in VB though.

Answer (score -3):

When you are in debug mode, go up to Debug on the menu bar, and go to the drop down menu of windows. There, you will see locals. This will tell you what values your variables are at your current breakpoints. You can also dive deep down into all of your objects as well through a tree menu. To look for a particular object, you can watch, and then input the variable you want to watch there. Make sure you have the breakpoints in the right place. Good luck!

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question