# Get variables in Watch Window while debugging in EnvDTE

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, envdte

The DTE object provides a way to capture all the variables that are in scope: dte.Debugger.CurrentStackFrame.Locals.

What method can I use to list all the variables in the watch window?

Answer (score 0):

[Constants.vsWindowKindWatch Field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.constants.vswindowkindwatch.aspx) is used to get a handle to a particular window in the integrated development environment (IDE) in order to gain access to its properties and methods.

But I don't find an class for Watch window in EnvDTE to help us show the variables. I suggest you list the variable in Output window with following sample code in below thread.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6930462/6593307