# Navigating within Visual Studio DataTip

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, datatip

When a DataTip is open while debugging in Visual Studio it appears the only way to get to a specific object property is scrolling with the mouse.

This can get very cumbersome as some objects can have hundreds of properties and scrolling to a property near the bottom takes a long time.

Yes, I know I can scroll faster if I hover the mouse over the bottom edge and pin a property once I found it but it can still take a long time to get to the property and pin it.

I've tried various combinations with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> but what ever key I press the DataTip is promptly closed...

Comment: You did not actually ask a question--you made only statements and observations. :)

Comment: Isn't it obvious what I'm asking? How do you jump to an entry in the list without all the scrolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the DataTip has focus, you don't have to use the mouse. You can use the <kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd> (Page Up/Page Down) keys on your keyboard. But you're right: There is not a way to get to the end of the list or to get to items that start with a certain letter. When I need to do that often I take one of two approaches:

1. If possible, I create a [temporary] variable assignment after the code-line of interest and ensure that the variable gets assigned to the property of interest.
2. Create a watch variable and interact with that.
3. Open an Immediate Window and paste a copy of the object-instance name in question. Once in the Immediate Window, IntelliSense is available as soon as you type the "."--you can then type the letter of the property in question and drill-down as needed more quickly.

**(Probaby the best tip!)**

4. Open (and keep open for convenience) a Debug | Windows | Autos and/or Debug | Windows | Locals window. Those windows simplify navigating variables near the code break or in the current module--and they even seem to retain their tree-node-expanded state in some cases while debugging. More information is available here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhawk8xd.aspx

Comment: I've done 1. but I'd avoid it. It's way too easy to forget removing it once no longer needed...

Comment: I agree with (1)--at least (2) and (3) are not code-invasive. I do hope Microsoft improves that DataTip window, for crying out loud. No one should need a third-party tool to address that. I get the lazy-loading approach--I don't get why keys were restricted to PgUp/PdDn, however. I added a (4)--I actually think that's the best tip of all, one I'm going to use myself!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the oz-code as an extension tool which could help you search the properties or variables easily.

[Search in debug mode inside an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925307/search-in-debug-mode-inside-an-object)

Comment: Makers of oz-code think their product is more valuable than ReSharper... not acceptable.