# How to debug large lists of strings and multidimensional arrays of numbers?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, visual-studio-2012, visualization

I often use C# to work with large datasets, which take the form of very large lists of strings, or large 2 or 3 dimensional arrays of numbers. The latter especially is very easy to visualize in Matlab, a functionality I often miss with C#.

VS2012 has very nice debugging functions which allow you to stop execution and inspect different variables in various ways. It will also highlight variables that change with red.

Unfortunately, for lists and matrices this is useless. By default, lists will not be expanded, and if you do expand them the values of individual entries will not be visible unless you expand every single one individually. The layout is uneconomical with space, so you can see few entries at one time. With larger 2D arrays, the way the entries are arranged makes interpreting the array at a glance a nightmare.

For datasets, there is a great visualization tool that automatically shows up when you click the magnifying glass in debug mode. Unfortunately, I can't find anything similar to it for lists of strings, string arrays, or 2D arrays of numbers.

Is there an extension or hidden feature for viewing such data structures when execution is paused? If no, how can I make my own?

Comment: `Console.Writeln` is your friend :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Unfortunately, that is a limited solution. Writing to console is quite expensive if done thousands of times, and the console can only display so much data (both number of symbols and color is limited).

Comment: @MitchWheat Ironically enough, that poster has not yet accepted my answer. :) Sorry Mitch, I was away from my computer for a while. Your answer was very helpful, thank you!

Comment: overriding ToString is fast and very useful.

Comment: @GameAlchemist Indeed, but I want faster, comparable to Matlab's `imagesc`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can write your own custom [Visualizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2zc529c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

- [Walkthrough: Writing a Visualizer in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164759.aspx)
- [How to: Install a Visualizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb2yca43.aspx)

There is also this:

- [Array Visualizer](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eedc48e7-5169-40d3-b602-ad451990a420)

> Array Visualizer is a free, open source extension for visual studio.
>   It is designed to display 2D, 3D and 4D arrays while debugging an
>   application.

Answer (score 0):

To me, Quickwatch (shift + F9) is way better than what you get as the default inspection in VS (to me that would be the hovering tooltips and the watch windows).

Also have a look at this: [search for a value in an object at runtime [QuickWatch enhancement]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275078/search-for-a-value-in-an-object-at-runtime-quickwatch-enhancement)
Using immediate window and ?yourlist should give what you want.

I just hope immediate window will do linq at some point, then you can do real magic. :)